# Is it possible to implement Google/CloudFlare DNS into an Android Webview App?

Tags: android-studio

I wish to add Google/CloudFlare DNS to a Webview Android App that I have, so the user will connect to the website in the app through the Google/CloudFlare DNS (8.8.8.8/1.1.1.1)
If it's possible, please, please write instructions as detailed as possible. That would be super helpful
Thank you and have a great weekend

Comment: any update with this?